# From an underscore.js template to a DOM element

Tags: jquery, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

Right now I'm using the following line of code to retrieve an Underscore template and create a DOM element from the template, using jQuery.

```
var element = $(_.template($('#template').html())());
```

It works, but I think this looks a bit messy/confusing, so I was wondering if there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated for Underscore 1.7+**: There's really not much better you can do in newer versions of Underscore since [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) always returns a function:

> **template** `_.template(templateString, [settings])`
>   Compiles JavaScript templates into functions that can be evaluated for rendering.

You used to be able to say `_.template(tmpl, data)` (see below) to get a filled-in template but no longer.

You can however hide some of the parentheses inside a function with things like:

```
var tmpl_to_html = function(id) {
    var $el = $('#' + id);
    var fn  = _.template($el.html());
    return fn();
};
var $e = $(tmpl_to_html('template'));
```

or:

```
var tmpl_to_html = function(id, data) {
    var $el = $('#' + id);
    var fn  = _.template($el.html());
    return fn(data);
};
var $e = $(tmpl_to_html('template'));
var $x = $(tmpl_to_html('other', { a: 'b' }));
```

---

**For old versions of Underscore:** You can get the filled in template from `_.template` by supplying the `data` parameter:

> **template** `_.template(templateString, [data], [settings])`
>   [...]
>   If you're writing a one-off, you can pass the **data** object as the second parameter to **template** in order to render immediately instead of returning a template function.

Anything truthy will probably due for `data` but an empty object is probably your best bet:

```
var $e = $(_.template($('#template').html(), { }));
```

That's still a bit noisy but you can always wrap the `_.template` call in another function:

```
var tmpl_to_html = function(id) {
    var $el = $('#' + id);
    return _.template($el.html(), { });
};
var $e = $(tmpl_to_html('template'));
```

How you bust it into functions depends on your preference what parts you'd be using elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, this looks a lot better. Splitting it up in functions is a good idea, and I must've missed the part about passing the data parameter.